# How to start Flash from Java on Mac OS X?

Tags: java, macos, flash, jsfl

I am creating a cross platform script in Java that will start Flash and execute some JSFL scripts.

I found this article [Executing JSFL from the Command Line on OS X](http://www.mikechambers.com/blog/2004/02/20/executing-jsfl-from-the-command-line-on-os-x/)

**Works from command line**

```
osascript -e 'tell application "Flash" to open posix file "/var/...tmp/sample.jsfl"'
```

**Does not work from Java**, like this:

```
String flashExe = "Flash";
String jsflFile = "/var/...tmp/sample.jsfl";

MessageFormat osascriptFormat = new MessageFormat("''tell application \"{0}\" to open posix file \"{1}\"''");
String osascript = osascriptFormat.format(new Object[]{flashExe, jsflFile});
String[] commands = new String[]{"osascript", "-e", osascript};

ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(commands);
pb.start();
```

**Question is**: How to start Flash from Java on Mac OS X?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy... according to this article [[HOW TO] Launch Application from Terminal?](http://macosx.com/forums/howto-faqs/29520-how-launch-application-terminal.html)

```
String jsflPath = "/var/...tmp/sample.jsfl";    
File jsflFile = new File(jsflPath);
jsflFile.setExecutable(true);
String[] commands = new String[]{"open", jsflFile.getAbsolutePath() };

ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(commands);
pb.start();
```

or

```
String[] commands = new String[]{"open", "-a", "Adobe Flash CS5", jsflFile.getAbsolutePath()};
```